# Windows GPO or system settings to allow network configuration by non-administrators

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, uac, gpo

I'm working on a Windows 8 platform for which i would like standard user to change the IP Address of the device. From my C# application I'm using the WMI interface, requesting settings from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class, and this works like a charm when application runs with Administrator privileges (based on this project https://github.com/NitroAMD/IPv4NICSettingsTool).

For my system use case, the device auto logon as a lambda user with no rights and my app is launched (using the shell Launcher of WES 8). So this app doesn't have any Administrator privileges and this is a main problem when trying to access the network interface configuration. I don't want lambda user to enter any user accounts name or password to perform the network configuration.

**So is their any GPO or system settings that could allows my application to perform those network configuration operations ?**

Comment: You could use a GPO for this; but you would also need to purchase a special software called BeyondTrust PowerBroker, one of the cool things PowerBroker can do is elevate the privileges of pre-identified software to run under administrative privileges.  Once PowerBroker is installed, you can setup a GPO which runs anything calling that software, even non-pprivledged accounts, to run under administrative privileges.  The rules which you can create are very granular.  PowerBroker is known as a Privileged Access Management (PAM) type of product.

Comment: Interesting, although I will first look for solutions not requiring 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your user to the local group of "network configuration operators".